# What expression can be used in a formula to represent an entire sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

`1:2` represents the first two rows, `A:B` represents the first two columns.

What expression represents the whole worksheet? **(No VBA.)**

EDIT: Selecting the whole sheet makes the expression `1:1048576` appear in my version of excel. That suggests there isn't anything better.

Comment: This is rather vague. It would help if you explain what you are doing so we can answer correctly, because working in VBA it will be different than if you are working with formulas.

Comment: @CharlieRB  Specifically, I'm looking to use the `INDEX` function of the entire worksheet and it requires a range expression.

Comment: Please edit your question to add these details so readers don't have to sift thru the comments to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Also, if you tell us what you are trying to accomplish OVERALL, we may be able to suggest a solution other than what you think it should be.

Comment: Alhough referring to the whole sheet is possible (as you already included in your question), it probably won't be the most efficient way. Telling us more details we may help finding a better formula.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Interestingly, making a sum over these many cells still delivers the sum without noticeable delay. I guess excel doesn't really address all those cells. Definitely fast enough.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You could just select all cells and give it a named range, but without more information your question doesn't make much sense. Especially because you'll get a circular reference if you're trying to do anything on the sheet

Comment: Referencing the entire worksheet within INDEX is something I do regularly. I usually prefer A:XFD for brevity, though in any case, when I commit the formula, Excel insists on changing this to the equivalent 1:1048576!

Comment: @Raystafarian Referencing cells as a range within INDEX will not per se incur a circular reference unless the resolution of that INDEX refers to the cell in which the formula lies. Since INDEX generally only resolves to a single cell reference, this would appear an unlikely event.

Comment: @XORLX fair enough. You should post an answer with that example, I'd upvote you - I think that's probably what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the entire worksheet within `INDEX` is something I do regularly. I usually prefer `A:XFD` for brevity, though in any case, when I commit the formula, Excel insists on changing this to the equivalent `1:1048576`!

Regards